# Equal and unequal partition?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, integer-partitions

Can someone please tell me what equal and unequal partition is?  And if the question, I'm just putting an example here, is asking you to find at least 3 equal and unequal partitions of 2020 into 4 parts with a span of 8, how am I suppose to tackle this question.

Thank you.

Comment: I, for one, don't know what an equal/unequal partition refers to. It might help if you told us where exactly you encountered these terms (i.e. the name/author of the textbook).

Comment: It's from the 2017 challenge stage intermediate student problems.  And yes, we are allowed to use computers to help us as stated in rule no.3 and the question that I asked wasn't directly from the booklet anyway.

Comment: Is that from the *Mathematics Challenge for Young Australians*?

Comment: Yes, and it's the intermediate one.